# Should we merge all i18n related tags into one?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

We have currently these i18n related tags:

- [localization](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization)
- [internationalization](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) with the synonym "i18n"

They both [describe technically different approaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization#Nomenclature), but I doubt that the average AN.SX users is aware of this. On Android i18n is the way to go, yet the majority of the questions is tagged with "localization".

I suggest merging all i18n related tags into one tag. But I am not sure which tag it should be.

Comment: It probably makes sense for them to be synonyms.  If `localization` is the majority, that's what I'd go with.  It also makes more sense to me -- users want the device to be localized, the don't care if the manufacturer has fully internationalized.

Comment: @MatthewRead That's what I meant with merging. Make "internationalization" and "i18n" synonyms of "localization". :)

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
updating post history, 9 rows affected
updating posts, 7 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 3 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [localization] and [internationalization] complete!
remapping 1 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym internationalization -> localization was approved
```